# Presenting a view controller and dismissing it disables keyboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a view that is presented, but when I dismiss that same view, and try to edit a text field on the original view, I can see the flashing cursor in the text field, but the keyboard doesn't appear. Only calling this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Note: this only seems to be an issue on the iPhone 4 running iOS 7, not sure if this indicates a bug or not. Thank you.

Comment: `[self.view endEditing:YES]` will resign the first responder. Which means your keyboard will hide. so remove it

Comment: Did you run on real device or simulator?

Comment: Bluewings, that's not the solution - I need the keyboard to hide because the view is nested inside a UIScrollView anyway. Even removing that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Works as desired in the simulator, doesn't work in physical iPhone 4 @ iOS 7.

Comment: you can run on simulator or Device?

Comment: On the simulator things work well with the software keyboard, but on the device it doesn't work.